# Excel 2016 showing wrong formula results, but the Functon Arguments Dialog shows correct result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying several formulas in Excel and have run into this problem with multiple formulas.  I put in a formula that should work, but excel displays the wrong result.  If I click on the function button to look at the arguments - the dialog box shows the correct value!

For example, if cell A1 = "DE1" and A2 has `=MIN(FIND(ROW($1:$10)-{1},A1&56^7))`
Excel has a 7 in cell A2, but if I edit the function I see the proper value of 2.

My ultimate goal is to strip all numbers from a cell using a formula (I don't want VBA code)  I have seen some examples online, but all show the same symptoms as the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula:

```
=MIN(FIND(ROW($1:$10)-{1},A1&56^7))
```

Is an array formula, which, to answer your question, needs to be be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

what the formula is doing:

```
A1&56^7
```

Creates a text string with the value of A1 and `1727094849536` which is `56^7` it also is a number that has all the digits from 0-9 in it.  This keeps the FIND from returning an error.

The

```
ROW($1:$10)-{1}
```

Returns an array of all the single digits: `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` in that order.

NOTE: the `{}` around the one is not needed, it does not do anything in this instance and can be omitted. `ROW($1:$10)-1`

The Find then in Array form will return an array of the first character position of each of those numbers.  So in the case of `A1&56^7` being `DE11727094849536` the array would be : `{8,3,6,15,10,14,16,5,11,9}`.

From that the MIN would return the `3`.

Without the Ctrl-Shift-Enter the FIND will not iterate through the array and only return the first, or `8` and the MIN of one number is that number.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.

Comment: @Scott Craner, Awesome explination

Comment: I meant to ask earlier but got interrupted at work.  Is that 56^7 trick for all digits but one a known programmers shortcut for expression all the digits shorter than 1234567890?

Comment: @ForwardEd it was new to me, but it works.  I will now steal it and use it.